# Redirect loop when accessing soundcloud feed

Tags: soundcloud

I was redirected here by the SoundCloud support, because apparently their developers are following the soundcloud tag.

I'm trying to access a particular feed published by soundcloud at
http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/29254752-manschool/tracks

When accessing the feed in the browser it works perfectly fine. However when using the Python feedparser library the SoundCloud server seems to respond with a redirect loop. I have captured the HTTP traffic at the following link
https://gist.github.com/stefankoegl/5604363

From my point of view it looks like a soundcloud bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does look like a problem on our side, but it appears there's a workaround. It seems like the redirect is being caused by a certain combination of `Accept` header. If you explicitly set it to `application/rss+xml` it works fine. Example in Python:

```
import feedparser

url = 'http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/29254752-manschool/tracks'
feed = feedparser.parse(url, request_headers={
    'Accept': 'application/rss+xml'
})

print feed
```

I'll follow up internally to see if we can get the problem fixed on our side, but I'd recommend using the above workaround for the time being.